# error on ExecuteNoQuery()

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, executenonquery

i'am trying to update a row in a table using :

```
command.ExecuteNoQuery()
```

it's not giving me an error but it's not updating the row

This is my code :

```
Dim req As String = "Update Table Set Id= 5"
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(req, connect())
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
disconnect()
```

thanks

Comment: What command are you executing?

Comment: I'm executing an Update command.

Comment: You know that sql query will update _every_ row in your table, and do you have a plan for reclaiming connections if an exception is thrown by your query (right now your disconnect() function wouldn't be called)

Comment: I know but this query is not doing anything, even if it's working with INSERT command.

Comment: what is the error being thrown? Have you tried running that sql directly against the db?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ID isn't an [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28SQL.80%29.aspx) column.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the query was too slow with `MS Access`.

Now it's working fine `MS SQL Server`.